# ffmpeg cutting off most audio when adding metadata tags

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mp3, metadata

I'm trying to add metadata id3v2.3 tags to some files I converted to mp3 using VLC media player. Here's the command I'm using:

```
ffmpeg -i "100000A9.mp3" -id3v2_version 3 -write_id3v1 1 -metadata title="titlename" -metadata artist="artistname" -metadata album="albumname" -b:a 320k "100000A9.mp3"
```

Unfortunately, when I do this I get the following output:

```
    ffmpeg version N-79630-g9ac154d Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.3.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --
enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-lib
modplug --enable-libmfx --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-
libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enabl
e-libschroedinger --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable
-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --ena
ble-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx
264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable
-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 22.101 / 55. 22.101
  libavcodec     57. 38.100 / 57. 38.100
  libavformat    57. 34.103 / 57. 34.103
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 44.100 /  6. 44.100
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
[mp3 @ 0000000001e42b80] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurat
e
Input #0, mp3, from '100000A9.mp3':
  Duration: 00:04:32.56, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 320 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 320 kb/s
File '100000A9.mp3' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
[mp3 @ 00000000006271e0] Using AVStream.codec to pass codec parameters to muxers
 is deprecated, use AVStream.codecpar instead.
Output #0, mp3, to '100000A9.mp3':
  Metadata:
    TIT2            : titlename
    TPE1            : artistname
    TALB            : albumname
    TSSE            : Lavf57.34.103
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 320 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.38.100 libmp3lame
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mp3 (native) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
size=      67kB time=00:00:01.64 bitrate= 331.1kbits/s speed=10.2x
video:0kB audio:65kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing ov
erhead: 1.915571%
```

As you can see, the file ends up outputting to 67kb and being only 1.64 seconds in length. The tags are correctly added, but the entire file is ruined.

FFmpeg does see the correct size at first (the 4:32.56), but for some reason it refuses to output correctly. This isn't the same thing as what other people are having when a few seconds are lost. The entire file is gone. I checked and played the file too, all that's there is the 1.64 beginning seconds. Does anyone understand why?

Comment: `-b:a 320k` re-encodes, but it sounds like you just want to append ID3 info. Do you get the desired result by eliminating this option from the command line?

Comment: @Yorik The problem is, if I do that, then ffmpeg by default re-encodes at a bitrate of 128 kb/s. If you could tell me how to make ffmpeg use the same bitrate as the input file, that would be most appreciated. EDIT: never mind,  I saw your other mention of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FFmpeg does not do any in-place editing or processing of files!!

By specifying the output file the same as the input file, ffmpeg wipes the file clean and only the packets initially read into memory before the output token is acted upon gets encoded and written.

You should always specify a output file different than the input.

That said, this is how you would add or change tags

```
ffmpeg -i "current.mp3" -id3v2_version 3 -write_id3v1 1 \
  -metadata title="titlename" -metadata artist="artistname" -metadata album="albumname" \
  -c:a copy "new.mp3"
```

Comment: and the `-c:a copy` avoids reencoding, which is good

Comment: Thank you, that seems to have resolved it. The thing is, I could've sworn I had had the output the same as the input before and got a functional conversion. I might be mistaken, though.